# django - How do you enter information from a list displayed on the webpage. For example filling a marksheet of learners

Tags: html, windows, django-views, django-forms

| Name | Mark |
| --- | --- |
| Jane | 78 |
| Ann | 60 |

i tried displaying a django form in table from (form.as_table) but didnot produce the results i expected.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I Want to end up with such an editable table whereby the list of students is displayed on the webpage and marks are entered just like you would enter date in  in excel or word. Do you know of  a django app or any other way  that I can use to achieve that?

Comment: You should look into [Django formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/formsets/)